# Java Servlets - Runnable (scheduled) function is executed twice in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets, amazon-ec2, tomcat9

I have setup a scheduled task to run every day in my Java servlet webapp, but the problem is that it runs twice every day. This problem only occurs when it is deployed to AWS EC2, when I run the same code locally on my computer via Eclipse it executes the scheduled task only once (as intended).

There is another part that I don't understand, ever since I have implemented the below classes, I have to startup Tomcat twice on AWS for the webapp to be online and accessible via the web. If I only run Tomcat once, the webapp will not be online and I get the "webpage not found" error on my browser when entering the URL for my site.

I have searched for similar issues here on Stack Overflow but have not found much information about what could be causing this issue.

Why is the following code running twice on AWS EC2 and only once on my local computer via Eclipse? How can I resolve this issue on AWS?

**ScheduleManager class:**

```
package com.schedule;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import com.schedule.task.NonSubmittedTimesheetNotificationSchedule;

@WebListener
public class ScheduleManager implements ServletContextListener
{
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NonSubmittedTimesheetNotificationSchedule(event.getServletContext()), 0, 7*24*60*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

**NonSubmittedTimesheetNotificationSchedule class:**

```
package com.schedule.task;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import com.process.EmailModule;

public class NonSubmittedTimesheetNotificationSchedule implements Runnable
{
    private ServletContext context;

    public NonSubmittedTimesheetNotificationSchedule(ServletContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        EmailModule.sendEmailToManagers();
        EmailModule.sendEmailToUsers();
    }
}
```

**web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.session.ActiveSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CredentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.CredentialsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CredentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>username</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I do not think you should be mixing `@WebListener` with `web.xml`